# How can I publish docker images to a local docker registry from Visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, git, docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-registry

How can I publish docker images to a local docker registry from Visual studio 2017?

Can any of these GitHub, Gitlab, Bibucket or GOGS be used to do it?

Comment: there`s some tutorials online on how to create a local registry and create CI/CD for it. i know of one in Pluralsight, but is paid, so i guess you could find others somewhere else. you want to create CI/CD? you can do it in TeamCity, you can download it as a container and run it locally, tons of tutorials on that too.